# SSH communication to go through Tor

Tags: ssh, openssh, tor

I've been trying [this](https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TorifyHOWTO/Misc#SSH) more specifically the SSH: Method 3 (socat). At the end of the method it says:

If you want every SSH communication to go through Tor, you can even say :

```
Host *
ProxyCommand socat STDIO SOCKS4A:localhost:%h:%p,socksport=9050
```

so I setup my ssh_config file exactly like it is above. I restarted my openSSH service and execute: ssh 192.168.x.x

I am now connected through ssh. How do I know if the connection goes through Tor?

I check through pinky and the "Where" still shows me a the user name of the connection.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0):

You can ensure that the ssh connection is going via TOR using a packet capture tool like tcpdump or wireshark. If you see port 22 traffic to your intended destination, then your TOR arrangement isn't working.